# What does "constant rate" mean in universal composable commitment scheme?

Tags: commitments, universal-composability

I'm wondering what does the "constant rate" mean in universal composable commitment scheme? I have known the rate of a commitment scheme is message length divided by the communication complexity of the scheme. What's the "constant" mean here? Must the constant be a number less than 1?

Comment: Can you please post a reference to a paper or something where you encountered this term?

Answer (score 4):

Constant rate in general means that the overhead from a non-secure method is constant. So, in a simple way, if I am committing to an $\ell$-bit message, then the size of the commitment is $O(\ell)$. In some cases, however, one also allows an additive factor that is independent of the message size. Thus, for example, it could be that to commit to a message of size $\ell$ the amount is $O(\ell)+{\rm poly}(n)$, where $n$ is the security parameter.

Note that typically these are measured in an amortized manner. So, you have to send many commitments (or a long message) for it to be true. But, again, this depends on the exact scheme, so you'll have to read the details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question: how large the size of the commitment is would be regarded as bad? For example, if the size of the commitment is O(nl) for committing l-bit message, where n is security parameter, is it bad?

Comment: Good or bad depends on your setting and what you want. In general, $O(n\cdot\ell)$ is of course much worse than $O(\ell)+poly(n)$, but if you want to commit to a little bit only, sometimes a simpler scheme is better.